# using interface is always helpful?

Tags: c#

Note: This question is related to an advice rather than an issue.

I would like to know when I should use an interface and when I should not.

In order to make it clear about my question, I am going to write my current implementation with and without interface:

**WITH INTERFACE**

```
interface IObjectBuilder
{
   string Build();
}

class ObjectABuilder: IObjectBuilder
{
    ObjectABuilder(Object A){}
    
    public string Build();
}

class ObjectBBuilder: IObjectBuilder
{
    ObjectBBuilder(Object B){}
    
    public string Build(){}
}
```

**WITHOUT INTERFACE 1:**

```
class ObjectABuilder
{
    ObjectABuilder(Object A){}
    
    public string Build(){}
}

class ObjectBBuilder
{
    ObjectBBuilder(Object B){}
    
    public string Build(){}
}
```

**WITHOUT INTERFACE 2:**

```
class ObjectABuilder
{   
    public string Build(Object A){}
}

class ObjectBBuilder
{
    
    public string Build(Object B){}
}
```

So, I would like to know, in this case:

1. Should I use with and without interface and why?
2. For the case of using without interface, what do you think of constructing the class with objectA (b) is better or just pass it directly in the method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I see class name ObjectABuilder, I suppose it creates ObjectA for me. But in this case I have to pass existing ObjectA to 'builder'. And it will return some string to me. Maybe it is Serializer? How do you actually use those builders?

Comment: yes, builder is to serialize an object to a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't always need an `interface`.  They'll reach a point where you do, perhaps you want to share with another module, and you'd rather it only took a dependency on an `interface` rather than a concrete implementation?  Perhaps you want to test implementation of an interface for a unit test?  I'd say start without an interface until you can demonstrate you need it.

For your second question, do other methods in the class need that `Object`?  If yes, then I'd pass it in the constructor so that those methods can share that `Object`.  If not then I'd keep it passed in.

The common theme is to [DTSTTCPW](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork)

Answer (score 3):

Like always there is no answer valid for all cases:

You could read the [Choosing Between Classes and Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229013.aspx) from MSDN Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries for more insight.

However those guidelines are targeted at Class Libraries, the guidelines could be more or less different for other types of projects. (IE: when using DI it's favorable to use interfaces over classes)

Using interfaces "is" a best practice but all the considerations should be taken into account, versioning, inheritance, forward and backward compatibility, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of arguments that come into play.

If you look at the classic book about Design Patterns they state:

> Program to an interface, not an implementation

This means that when using another class you should only look at the interface and not think about the implementation. For example:

> I know that method Bla on class Foo depends on method Boo, so I should
>   first call Boo and then Bla

Programming to an interface makes your code less coupled and improves [testability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testability). 
In C# you have the explicit concept of an interface in the language. Using that can help you with designing good interfaces and swapping the implementation as needed. When it comes to testing and things like [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), interfaces are a must have.

However, you also have the [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) principle (You ain't gonna need it). If your software isn't that complex then why introduce interfaces and make your code (slightly) harder to develop.

Answer (score 1):

Not using interfaces is a matter of choice. Making an interface for the class essentially just creates a 'guideline' for inherting the class so that you implement all the properties and methods that are essential to inheriting from an abstract class. For simpler classes this problem might not be apparent, but when you move to very complex classes with multiple levels of inhertiance, interfaces really do help in keeping your sanity in check.